# JRE insufficient memory issue even though with enough memory?

Tags: java, linux, memory, jvm, garbage-collection

I was running a JAVA program on a linux OS server and trying to push some information to RabbitMQ.
Somehow the program was interrupted because of an *Out of Memory Error*. I'm trying to investigate more and figure out the reason, but the content in the log file is very rich and I would like to seek some help because I'm also new to Java.

I won't expect I get the answer directly here (but I will be very happy if I can), just want to get the right direction so that I won't waste too much time.
Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

below is some valuable information

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 55574528 bytes for committing reserved memory.

#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2795), pid=43653, tid=0x00007f46186b4700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_332-b09) (build 1.8.0_332-b09)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.332-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f46280ea000):  VMThread [stack: 0x00007f46185b5000,0x00007f46186b5000] [id=43657]

Stack: [0x00007f46185b5000,0x00007f46186b5000],  sp=0x00007f46186b3330,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xb65ecd]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x1cd
V  [libjvm.so+0x5075aa]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*)+0xaa
V  [libjvm.so+0x941588]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0xd8
V  [libjvm.so+0x938d9e]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x2e
V  [libjvm.so+0x9b902b]  PSVirtualSpace::expand_by(unsigned long)+0x5b
V  [libjvm.so+0x9a90ca]  PSOldGen::expand_by(unsigned long) [clone .part.113]+0x2a
V  [libjvm.so+0x9a929b]  PSOldGen::expand(unsigned long) [clone .part.115]+0xdb
V  [libjvm.so+0x9a9be8]  PSOldGen::resize(unsigned long)+0x198
V  [libjvm.so+0x9af58c]  PSParallelCompact::invoke_no_policy(bool)+0x9dc
V  [libjvm.so+0x9b6b7d]  PSScavenge::invoke()+0x17d
V  [libjvm.so+0x968c73]  ParallelScavengeHeap::failed_mem_allocate(unsigned long)+0x63
V  [libjvm.so+0xb67b23]  VM_ParallelGCFailedAllocation::doit()+0x93
V  [libjvm.so+0xb6cfe5]  VM_Operation::evaluate()+0x55
V  [libjvm.so+0xb6afaa]  VMThread::evaluate_operation(VM_Operation*)+0x11a
V  [libjvm.so+0xb6b419]  VMThread::loop()+0x219
V  [libjvm.so+0xb6b8d2]  VMThread::run()+0x92
V  [libjvm.so+0x93e4f2]  java_start(Thread*)+0xf2

VM_Operation (0x00007f463172d3e0): ParallelGCFailedAllocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x00007f4628063800
```

What I see here is I get enough free memory to allocate (MemFree), right?

```
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

uname:Linux 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 5 16:57:59 UTC 2022 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.17 NPTL 2.17 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 4096, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:4.81 6.40 3.68

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        3861256 kB
MemFree:          108460 kB
MemAvailable:      19104 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:            22388 kB
SwapCached:         7600 kB
Active:          2577112 kB
Inactive:         971876 kB
Active(anon):    2570780 kB
Inactive(anon):   957160 kB
Active(file):       6332 kB
Inactive(file):    14716 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048572 kB
SwapFree:            780 kB
Dirty:                20 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       3519584 kB
Mapped:             3356 kB
Shmem:              1184 kB
Slab:              85128 kB
SReclaimable:      40496 kB
SUnreclaim:        44632 kB
KernelStack:        7872 kB
PageTables:        20908 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2979200 kB
Committed_AS:    3444760 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      183428 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359310332 kB
Percpu:            24064 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    448512 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       94016 kB
DirectMap2M:     4100096 kB
DirectMap1G:     2097152 kB
```

Comment: You should create a bug rport at openjdk

Answer (score 1):

> What I see here is I get enough free memory to allocate (MemFree), right?

No, an application cannot utilize all physical memory; Linux reserves a certain amount of free RAM exclusively for kernel use. This can be configured by [`vm.min_free_kbytes`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) sysctl option, the default is typically 44-66 MB.

```
$ sudo sysctl vm.min_free_kbytes
vm.min_free_kbytes = 45056
```

Even if there is enough free RAM, an allocation may fail because of other restrictions, like

- `vm.max_map_count`
- `vm.overcommit_memory`, `vm.overcommit_ratio`
- `RLIMIT_AS`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62360614/3448419) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will take a close look at your answer. Thanks again

Comment: Hi @apangin, I checked the content on the linked page you provided. And I found out that the value max_map_count is set as the default value which is 65535 in my Linux server. Just curious to know, how this value is calculated and I'm also not sure whether I should increase this value or not. ( I mean I checked online, ES instance has a baseline of 262144 for this parameter. All my Java program does is send information to RabbitMQ... which type of program should increase this value in your opinion? ) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Robinwong The linked answer tells that: `wc -l /proc/<pid>/maps`. However, in your case, the reason can be `vm.min_free_kbytes` I mentioned in the beginning.